# How to do a string comparison with a enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have a enum model as below,

```
public enum brand {
    Maxx,
    Rems,
    All
}
```

I have a WebAPI method, which accepts string brand as a parameter,

```
public IHttpActionResult GetItemDetails(string brand)
```

I need to do a string comparison of my input parameter brand against the enum.

Could one please suggest what is the best way to do it.

Comment: Did you do any research? Typing `c# compare string to enum` yields many results. Why did these not work for you?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I believe if you set the parameter type to the enum type then it will automagically convert it for you.